# Bucket Snapshots into TimeSeries Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a daily snapshot of data. Now I want to make a time series data from it using SQL. I have tried some method but it has certain limitation.

Sample Data:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

I have tried the following SQL but the limitation is that it give False result when logically two partitions should have been created for value 0 but instead only one is created.

```sql
SELECT [name], [value],
[date] as [start],
DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD([date], 1) OVER(PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date])) AS [end]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER(Partition by [name], [rnk] ORDER BY [date]) as row_num 
    FROM(
        SELECT [name], [value], [date],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(Partition by [name] ORDER BY [value]) AS rnk
        FROM sample_data
    ) AS T
) AS TT
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Result from above SQL:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a `gaps-and-islands` problem. You can try this.

```
SELECT Name, Value, MIN([Date]) Start, MAX([Date]) [End] FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name  ORDER BY [Date]) 
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Value ORDER BY [Date]) AS GRP
    FROM sample_data
) T 
GROUP BY Name, Value, GRP
ORDER BY Name, Start
```

Comment: I used the same logic but with "a with clause"

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution for the algorithms known as Islands and Gaps.

```
;WITH [Islands] AS 
(
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 0 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-24' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 0 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-25' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 0 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-26' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION

    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 1 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-27' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 1 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-28' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 1 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-29' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION

    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 0 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-30' AS DATE) AS [Date] UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS [Name], 0 AS [Value], CAST('2019-10-31' AS DATE) AS [Date]
)
, [IslandGroups] AS 
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', [Date]) AS [DifferenceInDays]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name], [Value]) AS [RowNumber]
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name], [Value]) AS [IslandGroup]
    FROM
        [Islands]
)
SELECT
    [Name]
    ,[Value]
    ,MIN([Date]) AS [starting_date]
    ,MAX([Date]) AS [starting_date]
FROM
    [IslandGroups]
GROUP BY
    [Name]
    ,[Value]
    ,[IslandGroup]
ORDER BY
    [Name]
    ,MIN([Date])
```

Here's how it works. The algorithm works by subtracting a ranking function, in this case ROW_NUMBER() from the difference in days between two dates. If you run this, you'll see that the RowNumber column increases as the DifferenceInDays does.

```
... removed for brevity
, [IslandGroups] AS 
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', [Date]) AS [DifferenceInDays]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name], [Value]) AS [RowNumber]
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, '1900-01-01', [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Name], [Value]) AS [IslandGroup]
    FROM
        [Islands]
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [IslandGroups]
```

Results in:

```
A   0   2019-10-24  43760   1   43759 <- First in the series
A   0   2019-10-25  43761   2   43759
A   0   2019-10-26  43762   3   43759
A   0   2019-10-30  43766   4   43762 <- Next set
A   0   2019-10-31  43767   5   43762
A   1   2019-10-27  43763   6   43757 <- Next set
A   1   2019-10-28  43764   7   43757
A   1   2019-10-29  43765   8   43757
```

You can then GROUP BY the common Island grouping and get the MIN() and MAX() [Date] from the same group.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d70be4/25)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table sample_data(Name varchar(max), Value int , Date date)
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',0,'2019-10-24')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',0,'2019-10-25')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',0,'2019-10-26')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',1,'2019-10-27')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',1,'2019-10-28')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',1,'2019-10-29')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',0,'2019-10-30')
insert into sample_data(Name,Value,Date)values('A',0,'2019-10-31')
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name  ORDER BY Date ) 
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Value ORDER BY Date  ) AS Interval
    FROM sample_data
  )


SELECT Name, Value, MIN(Date) Starting_Date, MAX(Date) Ending_Date FROM CTE    
GROUP BY Name, Value, Interval
Order BY Name,Starting_Date
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d70be4/25/0)**:

```
| Name | Value | Starting_Date | Ending_Date |
|------|-------|---------------|-------------|
|    A |     0 |    2019-10-24 |  2019-10-26 |
|    A |     1 |    2019-10-27 |  2019-10-29 |
|    A |     0 |    2019-10-30 |  2019-10-31 |
```